# Weather-API APIXU - Not providing necessary details (its working earlier but not now)

Tags: weather-api

We been using the weather-api apixu since 9 months, so far its working fine but suddenly its not. It is providing the name, region and country keys values as empty.

We have integrated the weather api apixu, its working so far in our stage environment and tested from postman too.

During our movement to production, its not sending the response as mentioned on their site.

API Request:
http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=abcdef&q=17.3850,78.4867

Here is the response. If you observe, name, region and country are empty strings. 
{
    "location": {
        "name": "",
        "region": "",
        "country": "",
        "lat": 17.39,
        "lon": 78.49,
        "tz_id": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "localtime_epoch": 1566731711,
        "localtime": "2019-08-25 16:45"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1566730926,
        "last_updated": "2019-08-25 16:32",
        "temp_c": 30,
        "temp_f": 86,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Partly cloudy",
            "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
            "code": 1003
        },
        "wind_mph": 10.5,
        "wind_kph": 16.9,
        "wind_degree": 260,
        "wind_dir": "W",
        "pressure_mb": 1006,
        "pressure_in": 30.2,
        "precip_mm": 0,
        "precip_in": 0,
        "humidity": 70,
        "cloud": 50,
        "feelslike_c": 35,
        "feelslike_f": 95,
        "vis_km": 6,
        "vis_miles": 3,
        "uv": 8,
        "gust_mph": 19.2,
        "gust_kph": 31
    }
}

Here is the expected output

{
    "location": {
        "name": "Kothaguda",
        "region": "Telangana",
        "country": "India",
        "lat": 17.39,
        "lon": 78.49,
        "tz_id": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "localtime_epoch": 1566731711,
        "localtime": "2019-08-25 16:45"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1566730926,
        "last_updated": "2019-08-25 16:32",
        "temp_c": 30,
        "temp_f": 86,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Partly cloudy",
            "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
            "code": 1003
        },
        "wind_mph": 10.5,
        "wind_kph": 16.9,
        "wind_degree": 260,
        "wind_dir": "W",
        "pressure_mb": 1006,
        "pressure_in": 30.2,
        "precip_mm": 0,
        "precip_in": 0,
        "humidity": 70,
        "cloud": 50,
        "feelslike_c": 35,
        "feelslike_f": 95,
        "vis_km": 6,
        "vis_miles": 3,
        "uv": 8,
        "gust_mph": 19.2,
        "gust_kph": 31
    }
}

For your reference, here is the example provided by their team.
The above request is for the current day but the below one is hour to hour.
https://www.apixu.com/doc/sample_hour_by_hour.json

Comment: i have the same problem its look like the cdn.apixu.com is not responding any more use another weather api
good luck